# NoClassDefFoundError after importing an external jar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

After importing JSoup, everytime the first line of Jsoup code is run, the app gives me this

```
09-16 16:43:22.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 16:43:22.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup
09-16 16:43:22.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at me.masterejzz.testapp.StartingPoint$1.onEditorAction(StartingPoint.java:55)
09-16 16:43:22.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.widget.TextView.onEditorAction(TextView.java:4185)
09-16 16:43:22.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.performEditorAction(EditableInputConnection.java:138)
09-16 16:43:22.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:297)
09-16 16:43:22.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
09-16 16:43:22.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-16 16:43:22.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-16 16:43:22.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-16 16:43:22.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

I have heavily researched this topic, and none of the fixes work for me like the lib folder thing, changing the order and export and many others. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con"            path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con"     path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/jsoup-1.7.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Did you use `libs/` or `lib/`

Comment: please post your class path file

Comment: does this happen when you run it out of Eclipse or with the packaged app on a Droid device?

Comment: This happens when I test it on a simulator in Eclipse.

Comment: Hmm, strange, one of my projects has the same configuration, with jar jsoup-1.7.2.jar 286 KB. Try to: remove this jar -> Clear Project -> add Jar -> clear Project -> refresh. BTW, remove old application from Android

Comment: Nope, that does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Go to Eclipse -> 
      right click on your Project ->
                       "Properties" ->
                          "Java Build Path" ->
                              "Order and Export" Tab
```

There check all boxes with attached jars.

Sometimes after, may need `clear` + `refresh` your project

Hope it will help you,

Comment: what if I don't have "Java Build Path" option there?

Comment: In my case, I needed to create libs folder in my main project folder and put the jar file inside it. After that, I followed the steps to add the external jar to the build path and used the above steps to tick the jar. Clean, run, problem solved!

Comment: The suggested solution worked just fine for me... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar `NoClassDefFoundError` error when adding a new jar to my JaveEE project. I followed the steps above make sure that the jar was properly included in the build path. However, I was still getting the error what done the trick for me was to remove and add the resource into the tomcat server.

```
- Go to Servers
- Right click on the server and select "Add and Remove"
- Pick the resource with the new jar then remove it and it
- Restart the server
```