# Adding an external jar to Order and Export build path generates error in project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse plugin which has it's Java code structured in multiple projects. In one of the projects I added an external jar and used some classes from it. At compilation time no errors where reported, but at runtime, a `NoClassDefFoundError` exception was thrown. I fixed the problem following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18837342/6594367) solution.

After this I run a `Project -> Clean..` and out of a sudden in a different project I have an error that `The method filter(Predicate<? super String[]>) in the type FluentIterable<String[]> is not applicable for the arguments ...`.

I compared the `FluentIterable` clasess in both situations and their origin does not modify.

Why is this happening?

Comment: How is it possible to split the code of an Eclipse plug-in into multiple projects? Please provide an [example to reproduce your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Which Eclipse version and which Java version do you use?

Comment: @howlger Using a Maven structure with dependencies between them. I found the problem. The imported Jar was using a different `FluentIterable`  class from `guava`, I was seeing the same origin for the class because I did not execute a clean when changing back the class path.

Comment: @howlger What is not clear to me is: since I set the build path only for the package which uses the external jar, why does it affect other packages ( in my case it affects a different PROJECT!)

Comment: I would think that using multiple projects for a single plugin is going to confuse Eclipse PDE and things are not going to work properly. Split the plugin in to multiple smaller plugins, one per project.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error because the imported jar was using a different `FluentIterable` class from a `guava` jar. I thought the class origin is the same because when I switched back the build path, I did not execute a `Project->Clean` and eclipse was still pointing to the bad class location.