# Modifying the build path of a project affects other projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I started with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47847270/6594367) problem which misslead me.

Long story short. I have an eclipse plugin with the code splitted in multiple projects(this is how they apper in eclipse in `Project Explorer`) with Maven nature.

In one of the projects I imported a jar `external.jar` which uses the class `FluentIterable` from `guava-15.0.jar`.

I updated the build path of the project to include in `Order and Export` the jar `external.jar`. After a `Project->Clean...`, another project which uses the `FluentIterable` class fails(now it points to the bad `guava` jar version from where it should be imported).

The question is: Why does updating the Build Path of a project affects other projects? Why the project does not consider the specified external jar but it looks in other projects for referenced libraries?

Comment: If a dependent project or resource is changed, the project is updated. Can you give a step-by-step instruction what exactly do you mean by _"now it points to the bad guava jar version from where it should be imported"_?

Comment: @howlger Solved this one too meanwhile. Consider having 3 eclipe plugins( I assume there are 3 becuase I see two different entries in project explorer which have inside a `plugin.xml`). Now, project A imports `guava-20.0.jar` and exports it (it is checked in `Order and Export` in the `Configure Build Path`). Project B uses  a class from that jar. Now project C imports the external jar `guava-25.0.jar`. Because project B in `manifest.mf` has as required plug-ins project C and project A in this order, it uses the class from the guava jar imported by project C which has a changed metho signature.