# Using external package in eclipse - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I was trying to use `Base32` from `org.apache.commons.codec`. After I downloaded the package, I added the JARS to my Project Build Path in Eclipse by following [this guide(part 5 of 5: Adding External JARs)](https://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)) . I typed out my code and the IDE didn't have problem identifying the class in the package:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.*;

public class Authenticator {

    public static String generateSecretKey() {
        SecureRandom generator = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[20];
        generator.nextBytes(bytes);
        Base32 base32 = new Base32();
        return base32.encodeToString(bytes);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generateSecretKey();

    }

}
```

When I attempted to run my code, I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base32
at Authenticator.generateSecretKey(Authenticator.java:11)
at Authenticator.main(Authenticator.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base32
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 2 more
```

I have tried using different methods in [the guide](https://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)) to add my JARs with no success. I have also tried solution proposed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837311/noclassdeffounderror-after-importing-an-external-jar), and still got the same error.

Any help is much appreciated!

**Edit:**
This is my .classpath file if it is of any help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-14">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Library/commons-codec-1.14/commons-codec-1.14-javadoc.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Library/commons-codec-1.14/commons-codec-1.14-sources.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Library/commons-codec-1.14/commons-codec-1.14-test-sources.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Library/commons-codec-1.14/commons-codec-1.14-tests.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Library/commons-codec-1.14/commons-codec-1.14.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` file? If so, try deleting it.

Comment: I don't have 'module-info.java' file in my project directory

Comment: Which jars did you add?

Comment: @nitind I edit my post to include the .classpath file. I added 5 .jars as listed

Comment: You can safely remote the test, sources, and javadoc jars. They don't contain runtime code.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the project and right click
[click the build path and then add external archives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8a3D.png)

[choose the jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQWAW.png)

and then choose the jar.

Comment: A pop-up windows saying 'Following archives are already on the build path and will not be added...". Same problem persists